# PayU Money Gateway iOS Swift

Tags: swift2, ios9.1, payu, payumoney

I want to integrate the payU Money sdk in my app using swift2.0

I am using this sdk: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.1-NEW-iOS-Seamless-SDK-integration

Where to create the test account for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

var merchantKey="your live merchant key"
var salt="your live merchant salt"
var PayUBaseUrl="https://secure.payu.in"

class PaymentScreen: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initPayment()
  }

  func initPayment() {

    var i = arc4random()

    let amount = "1"
    let productInfo = "Order"
    let firstName = "Sample name"
    let email = "abc@gmail.com"
    let phone = "9999119911"
    let sUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    let fUrl = "https://www.bing.com"
    let service_provider = "payu_paisa"

    let strHash:String = self.sha1(String.localizedStringWithFormat("%d%@", i, NSDate()))

    let rangeOfHello = Range(start: strHash.startIndex,
                             end: strHash.startIndex.advancedBy(20))
    let txnid1 = strHash.substringWithRange(rangeOfHello)

    let hashValue = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",merchantKey,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstName,email,salt)

    let hash=self.sha1(hashValue)

    let postStr = "txnid="+txnid1+"&key="+merchantKey+"&amount="+amount+"&productinfo="+productInfo+"&firstname="+firstName+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&surl="+sUrl+"&furl="+fUrl+"&hash="+hash+"&service_provider="+service_provider

    let url = NSURL(string: String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@/_payment", PayUBaseUrl))

    print("check my url", url, postStr)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    do {

      let postLength = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%lu",postStr.characters.count)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Current-Type")
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.HTTPBody = postStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    } catch {

    }

  }

  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    let requestURL = self.myWebView.request?.URL
    let requestString:String = (requestURL?.absoluteString)!

    if requestString.containsString("https://www.google.com") {
        print("success payment done")
    }
    else if requestString.containsString("https://www.bing.com") {    
        print("payment failure")
    }
  }

  func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    print("double failure")
  }

  func sha1(toEncrypt:String) -> String {
    let data = toEncrypt.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
    return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
  }
}
```

Comment: @Anirudh where to put the card details?

Comment: when I'm try ur solution it says

Use of unresolved identifier 'CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH'

Comment: @Anirudh : How to find whether payment success/failure? . I am skeptical about your checking for containsString() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Swift 4
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration
import Foundation

class PayUMoneyViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var merchantKey = "YOUR_MARCHANT_KEY"
    var salt = "YOUR_SALT_KEY"
    var PayUBaseUrl = "https://secure.payu.in"
    var SUCCESS_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/payments/guestcheckout/#/success"
    var FAILED_URL = "https://www.PayUmoney.com/mobileapp/PayUmoney/failure.php"

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.webView.delegate = self
        self.payPayment()

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(PayUMoneyViewController.back(sender:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton

    }

     @objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cancel !", message: "Do you really want to cancel the transaction ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: cancelTransaction))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func cancelTransaction( action : UIAlertAction)
    {
        _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func payPayment() {

        var i = arc4random()

        let amount = "1"
        let productInfo = "Transport"
        let firstName = USER_FIRST_NAME // Geet
        let email = USER_EMAIL // geetbasakare@gmail.com
        let phone = USER_MOBILE_NO // 1234567890
        let sUrl = "https://www.google.com"
        let fUrl = "https://www.bing.com"
        let service_provider = "payu_paisa"
        let strHash:String = self.sha1(toEncrypt: String.localizedStringWithFormat("%d%@", i, NSDate()));
        let r1 = strHash.range(of: strHash)!

        // String range to NSRange:
        let n1 = NSRange(r1, in: strHash)
        print((strHash as NSString).substring(with: n1)) //

        // NSRange back to String range:
        let r2 = Range(n1, in: strHash)!
        print(strHash.substring(with: r2))
        let rangeOfHello = Range(n1, in: strHash)!
        let txnid1 = strHash.substring(with: rangeOfHello)
        let hashValue = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",merchantKey,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstName,email,salt)

        let hash = self.sha1(toEncrypt: hashValue)

        let postStr = "txnid="+txnid1+"&key="+merchantKey+"&amount="+amount+"&productinfo="+productInfo+"&firstname="+firstName+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&surl="+sUrl+"&furl="+fUrl+"&hash="+hash+"&service_provider="+service_provider

        let url = NSURL(string: String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@/_payment", PayUBaseUrl))

        print("check my url", url as Any, postStr)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        do {

            let postLength = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%lu",postStr.characters.count)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Current-Type")
            request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.httpBody = postStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error)

        }

    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

        let requestURL = self.webView.request?.url
        let requestString:String = (requestURL?.absoluteString)!
        if (requestString == SUCCESS_URL) {
            print("success payment done")
        }
        else if (requestString == FAILED_URL) {
            print("payment failure")
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        print("double failure")
    }

    func sha1(toEncrypt: String) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        if let data = toEncrypt.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let value =  data as NSData
            CC_SHA512(value.bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)

        }
        var digestHex = ""
        for index in 0..<Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
            digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
        }

        return digestHex
    }

    /*
    func sha1(toEncrypt:String) -> String {
        var data = toEncrypt.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))

        _ = data.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
                CC_SHA512(messageBytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
            }
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined(separator: "")
    }
 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test account as described in the following help documentation, and you need not perform KYC in this regard. Later, you can use the Key and Salt on the Payment Gateway page of the Dashboard.
https://devguide.payu.in/low-code-web-sdk/getting-started-low-code-web-sdk/register-for-a-test-merchant-account/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33746890)