# How to integrate payment gate way in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm currently doing one app for that app I need to integrate payment gate way but don't know how to implement payu money in my app, from two days i'm just reading tutorials but still didn't get any solution I'm new to swift if any help it would be Awesome.

Comment: Which payment gateway you want to integrate mention you some code and explanation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908484/payu-money-gateway-ios-swift

Comment: Refer this answer to integrate PayU in iOS with Swift. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47234959/4201458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html
check this one, they added iOS sdk for Swift and objective c in payU money I hope its helpful for u.

Answer (score 1):

There is SDK and Example provided by PayU for swift at https://codeload.github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-IOS-SDK/zip/master

If you want to integrate payU then you have to make bridge to use the SDK.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Here is my answer for Swift 2.3, : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256507/3548469

You will easily able to convert in swift 3.0.

Comment: Hi dev My friend said use  Stripe framework its better to integrate is this better way to implement

Comment: Hi Sam,
You can use stripe , stripe is way easy and convenient to use when comparing to integration. If you payu is not compulsory then you should opt for stripe.

Comment: if pay u is not compulsory then you may go for stripe it totally upto you.

Comment: you asked you tried to integrate pay u money so answered solution for it.

Comment: Pay u Is compulsory for my app

Comment: https://comparisons.financesonline.com/stripe-vs-payu  here is the comparison between both

Comment: if compulsory then you must integrate pay u

Comment: https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html I seen here some iOS sdk for swift at the down

Comment: Yes same they have uploaded the swift version too

Answer (score 1):

This is helped me

```
 import UIKit

var merchantKey = "your live merchant key"
var salt = "your live merchant salt"
var PayUBaseUrl = "https://secure.payu.in"

class PaymentScreen: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.payPayment()
  }

  func payPayment() {

    var i = arc4random()

    let amount = "1"
    let productInfo = "product"
    let firstName = "SampleName"
    let email = "xxx@gmail.com"
    let phone = "9876543210"
    let sUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    let fUrl = "https://www.bing.com"
    let service_provider = "payu_paisa"

    let strHash:String = self.sha1(String.localizedStringWithFormat("%d%@", i, NSDate()))

    let rangeOfHello = Range(start: strHash.startIndex,
                             end: strHash.startIndex.advancedBy(20))
    let txnid1 = strHash.substringWithRange(rangeOfHello)

    let hashValue = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",merchantKey,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstName,email,salt)

    let hash=self.sha1(hashValue)

    let postStr = "txnid="+txnid1+"&key="+merchantKey+"&amount="+amount+"&productinfo="+productInfo+"&firstname="+firstName+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&surl="+sUrl+"&furl="+fUrl+"&hash="+hash+"&service_provider="+service_provider

    let url = NSURL(string: String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@/_payment", PayUBaseUrl))

    print("check my url", url, postStr)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    do {

      let postLength = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%lu",postStr.characters.count)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Current-Type")
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.HTTPBody = postStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    } catch {

    }

  }

  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    let requestURL = self.myWebView.request?.URL
    let requestString:String = (requestURL?.absoluteString)!

    if requestString.containsString("https://www.google.com") {
        print("success payment done")
    }
    else if requestString.containsString("https://www.bing.com") {    
        print("payment failure")
    }
  }

  func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    print("double failure")
  }

  func sha1(toEncrypt:String) -> String {
    let data = toEncrypt.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
    return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
  }
}
```